# QGIS: Display emojis in labels (or alternatively: how to have several symbols per point)

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, encoding, emoji

I have a set of data that uses emojis in one column of the attribute table. They appear correctly in the table, but I can't get them to appear on the map when I set their field as a label for the map.

[image: failed emoji]

In the example above I added some ordinary characters to illustrate better how the water drop icon is missing.**Why do I need emojis?**

I have point layer indicating villages and what is cultivated or herded there. I need to show these crops and animals on a map. Let's say it's:

- A. cereals and vine,
- B. vine,
- C. cereals and swine.

I need every element to be displayed separately. So two icons for A and C, and one icon for B.

I tried normal symbology with conditions, but it's basically impossible with around 12 symbols that I need. There's simply not enough space around the point for each symbol to have a permanently attributed spot (regardless of whether it actually appears or not).

So I was very happy to come up with this idea of emojis:

- A.
- B.
- C.

I spent some time preparing them in Excel, and then – crap, they don't appear in QGIS.

EDIT: I'm using 3.28.3-Firenze on most recent macOS.

EDIT2: Here's [sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/esdc7alach0ccw3/data%20sample.csv?dl=0).

(In the example above I added some ordinary characters to illustrate better how the water drop icon is missing.)

Comment: There's a lot of information missing like QGIS version you use, the exact emoji you use etc. In my case, a sample emoji shows in the label, just without colors. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFE1v.png

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: OK, do we speak about standard emojis or custom created ones? In the last case, I guess you have to stick to another solution like SVG or raster image marker

Comment: Standard emojis, like in the examples above.

Comment: For me, it works (just without colors, as mentioned): https://i.stack.imgur.com/efoDz.png Can you provide the project with sample data?

Comment: Change the font to Arial to see if the emojis appear. Not every font comes with every character.

Comment: Thank you. I just added sample data to the main post. I changed font to Arial even before coming here. It didn't work. What OS are you using?

Comment: I use Windows 10

Comment: This might rely on Qt etc. Iirc there is no way to get nice colored emojis in QGIS labelling sadly. But you should be able to use raster image renderers or something like that to emulate it.

Comment: Your data loads like this to QGIS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/326Wb.png - can you check how the emojis look like in attribute table (maybe post a screenshot)

Comment: @Babel: Beautiful. This would be perfect. Any idea why I can't have the same effect? I need to render them on Windows?

bugmenot123: I don't need them to be colored. The shapes shown by Babel would be perfect. As for the rasters, I mentioned above what's the problem: I need very divergent set of icons for each point. Any idea how to implement that?

Comment: No idea if Mac is the problem? I have QGIS 3.30.0, so maybe you want to try installing this. What about your attribute table: do the emojis appear there?

Comment: Yes, they appear in the attribute table. https://share.cleanshot.com/qrnBttm1 I'm downloading QGIS 3.30 right now.

Comment: In QGIS 3.30 emojis don't appear is labels neither. I even created an empty project and tested it there. Nothing. https://share.cleanshot.com/0fqgnLtd